# Data deleted from parse instllation table

Tags: parse-platform

My app is inserting/updating parse instllation table when user do login.

Yesterday 20-10-2015, i had 5 records in installtion table, suddenly 2 records have been deleted?.

I was not able to send push, when I checked I found 2 records for 2 users have been deleted from the instllation table!!

Any Idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a record from Installation class requires master key. This means you either have to delete the records directly from Parse dashboard or use your master key.